# Best way to get sql date comparisons with sysdate?- adding 30 days to due_date

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT *
FROM reciepts 
WHERE Remarks = 'PAID' and DATEADD(day,30,Due_date) =<SYSDATE
```

apparently i can't get this to work.I just want to show the tables that have been marked paid in my remarks table and then see if they are past their due date which has to be 30 days from there due dates.

my sql syntax error kicks in whenever i try to compare the sysdate value.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's useless to say you get an error then not quote it in full. Post it.

Comment: i want to get all data that has remarks = paid and due_date past 30 days.

Comment: Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        Dim querry As String = "SELECT Due_date, Client, DATEADD(day, 30, Due_date) AS DateAdd FROM Reciepts Where Dateadd =>Sysdate"

        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = vj7.accdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()

Comment: error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Dateadd =>Sysdate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, then in MS Access the syntax would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM reciepts
WHERE Remarks = "PAID" and DATEADD("d", 30, Due_date) < date();
```

It is better to get in the habit of putting the functions on the "constant" rather than the column:

```
SELECT *
FROM reciepts
WHERE Remarks = "PAID" and Due_date < DATEADD("d", -30, date());
```

Comment: Imma take note now how things work on sql date stuff